# vector of threads called from inside a class function

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdvector

I am trying to do something similar to the last code in  [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/unices/194352/#msg935726)

In the code however you see that
`vec_thr.emplace_back(&Test::testme, std::move(t1), std::cref(str));` is called inside the main function.

I would like to do that from a member function of the object Test.

So I did

```
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Test
{
private:
public:
    void testme(const std::string& _str)
    {
        std::cout << "Hello " + _str << std::endl;
    }
    void testFurther(const std::string& _str){
        
        std::vector<std::thread> vec_thr;
        // pass the constructor parameters you would have passed to std::thread
        // to the emplace_back() function - they are forwarded to the thread that
        // is constructed "in place" inside the vector
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
      //HERE I am trying how to write this correctly trying the following:
//           vec_thr.emplace_back(&Test::testme, std::move(t1), std::cref(str));
             vec_thr.emplace_back(testme, std::move(this), std::cref(_str));
//             vec_thr.emplace_back(testme, std::cref(_str));
        }
        // Don't forget to join all your threads to make sure
        // they complete before moving on/exiting
        for(auto& t: vec_thr)
          t.join();
        
    }
};

int main()
{
    const std::string str = "there";
    Test t1/*, t2*/;

    t1.testFurther(str);
}
```

However it is not working. I got the error message

```
error: invalid use of non-static member function
```

Is there a way to be able to do this.
I want to do the exact same thing that was done originally from the main function

Comment: Regarding the error, for pointers to member functions you need the address-of operator `&`. And don't do `std::move(this)`, just pass `this` as it is.

Comment: Don't understand your question now. Decide which version of the code you're asking us about, and tell us what goes wrong when you run it. Or are you asking about style? Also, describe the problem in the linked-to page, don't rely on content being available at the link; your question should be essentially self-contained.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I changed it and it seems to be working. (Put it in the question in an EDIT). I wonder why I have to use `&Test::testme` and not `this->` or something like this

Comment: @einpoklum The Edit was because it seems I solved it. But I am not an expert of threads so I wonder if there is anything wrong before putting that as an aswer

Comment: @KansaiRobot: Put it in an answer instead, and let others comment about the answer.

Comment: @einpoklum OK! Will do!

Answer (score 0):

It seems I have solve the problem by changing the class Test function testFurther to

```
void testFurther(const std::string& _str){
        
        std::vector<std::thread> vec_thr;
        // pass the constructor parameters you would have passed to std::thread
        // to the emplace_back() function - they are forwarded to the thread that
        // is constructed "in place" inside the vector
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
//           vec_thr.emplace_back(&Test::testme, std::move(t1), std::cref(str));
//             vec_thr.emplace_back(testme, std::move(this), std::cref(_str));
//               vec_thr.emplace_back(&testme, this, std::cref(_str)); // ISO forbid taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function



               vec_thr.emplace_back(&Test::testme, this, std::cref(_str)); //THIS WORKS

//             vec_thr.emplace_back(testme, std::cref(_str));
        }
        // Don't forget to join all your threads to make sure
        // they complete before moving on/exiting
        for(auto& t: vec_thr)
          t.join();
        
    }
```

with this it seems to be working well.
I just wonder why I have to use `&Test::testme` since Test is the name of the class not of an object instance

Comment: you have to use the `Test::` because how else would the language know which class whose member function you are forming a pointer to...? as for why you can't write e.g. `this->testme` instead, the answer is simply because the syntax of the language doesn't work like that. a pointer-to-member is written like `&ClassName::member_name` and cannot be written as `instance_ptr->member_name` or `instance_ref.member_name` . there are probably good reasons why it can't be done - e.g. ambiguity of parsing it as a pointer-to-member rather than just as an lvalue of the pointed-to type.